# open browser tab/windows in background

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, browser

I am stuck with a little problem from few days now.

There is some solution over internet but they don’t match what I need.

I’m on a Spring web application, using flex. For some reasons I need to load a new windows (or tab) in background.

For now I manage to write some JavaScript script that put the focus on the main window when the child one is created but when the main window get the focus back it select the whole text and so the user loose all his work.

It’s why the new window MUST NOT take the focus at any time.

I also tried to create a link and simulate the middle click on it so the tab is created in background, but it only work on Chrome, beside I see that on Internet Explorer the tab is sometime created in background sometime in foreground (even if the setting option: “Always switch to new tabs when they are created” is NOT setted on, i must miss something). 
Of course like in a lot of company the main browser is IE, so the solution must work for it, i can specify some setting to make the thing work as every user get the same env.

i've also tried to set the registry to make no application take focus but on 7 or 2008 RT it's not really usefull.

I’m looking for a solution in javascript, flex/AS or even html to create that tab without interrupting the user. If the main window loose the focus 1 sec but I manage to not select the whole text in flex it will be good too.

Thanks in advance.